# Configure Netbeans IDE for Play Framework

Tags: netbeans, playframework, javadoc

I know running:

```
play netbeansify
```

configures the IDE for the Play Framework.

My Problems:

- I have no JavaDoc for the Play Framework
- I cannot navigate to the Play Source

Has anyone managed to get that done.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been long since I used Netbeans so I can't give you the To link the full steps, but:

- The source is available [here](https://github.com/playframework/play/tree/master/framework/src). You'll need to link it as "code source" to your project. IntelliJ IDEA prompts me to browse for the source automatically when trying to browse it if it's not available, I don't know if Netbeans may have something similar

I assume once the source is linked the Javadoc in it will be available. There is not too much, I warn you (this is not like Maven projects where you have the 3 jars: source, binary and javadoc). But the code is simple and self-explanatory.